# Bad download of latest stable version

Tags: downloads

I paid $16 and tried to download the latest version last night and got only part of it (the file ends in ...iso.part). Can someone tell me how to finish getting it? I paid with PayPal.

Comment: That's quite a surprise. Who did you pay money and for what?

Comment: @jokerdino There's a big donation form on the download page these days.

Comment: He means this: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/questions?distro=desktop&bits=64&release=lts

Comment: @Oli Oh yeah... I remember now :S. But if it wasn't on the ubuntu.com page it could be bad.

Comment: You paid ? No you didn't pay anything. **Ubuntu is Free, Always has been and always will be !!** 
You made a contribution, that is what you did. You can skip this by clicking "Not now, take me to the download". As for you problem retry later or use an alternative download like [torrent](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)

Comment: .part usually means that Firefox did not complete the download. Just download it again, you do not need to donate once again, just skip that step.

Comment: @NikTh there are "donations" maybe OP wording was bad, check the answer below.

Answer (score 7):

Just go on the download page again and just hit "Not now, take me to the download ›" when you are asked if you want to make a **donation**. :)

See the image bottom left for the link (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/questions?distro=desktop&bits=64&release=lts):

[image]

### Alternatives

You can try the official [BitTorrent seeds](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) or use [Zsync](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ZsyncCdImage) ([for Windows](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/zsync-windows/new_dashboard)). But using a download manager that can continue aborted downloads would be the easiest option.

Comment: Here have an image for free :-D

Comment: Zsync is another alternative. It should even be able to continue with the partially downloaded file if it's not some fancy custom donwlod manager format.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `wget -c http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download?distro=desktop&bits=64&release=lts`

Just change **distro**="desktop" or "server";  **bits**="32" or "64";  **release**= "lds" or "latest" if you want to download a different one.

If you use the `-c` option with `wget`, it will check to see if you already have a download started with that name and will automatically continue it.

This is also handy next time a new release comes out and you don't want to click your way through the site to get to the download. :)

Comment: I suppose this answer assumes you're using a Linux based OS...